# Finding daily averages in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a video camera running 24/7

Every few hours or so someone logs in to review the last few hours of footage not yet reviewed

My table in google sheets takes the latest timestamp and subtracts it from the previous timestamp of the person who came before them and stores the difference as work done for the person who reviewed the footage.

A single person can review the footage in multiple instances a day. I need to gather the average amount of work done by each person per day.

I have no idea how to get this done in google sheets.

Edit: [here's an example of the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xr_LHnh-7LRPhcpiGP_ABfCl2AmAxt9EBEzkqYTpj_s/edit#gid=828900112), the report page is accurate to what the data will look like but not what the actual values are that will be returned.

Comment: Maybe you could include (a sanitized version of) the google sheet along with the answer(s) you are expecting to calculate.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @player0 it has been done

Comment: @player0 it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 {'All hours'!E2:E, TIMEVALUE('All hours'!I2:I), 'All hours'!D2:D}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where lower(Col3) = '"&LOWER(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, ": (.*)"))&"' 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)'' 
  format sum(Col2)'[hh]:mm'", 0));
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 {'All hours'!E2:E, DATEVALUE('All hours'!F2:F), 
 TIMEVALUE('All hours'!I2:I), 'All hours'!D2:D}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
  where lower(Col4) = '"&LOWER(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, ": (.*)"))&"' 
  group by Col1,Col2 
  label sum(Col3)''", 0), 
 "select avg(Col2) 
  group by Col1 
  label avg(Col2)'' 
  format avg(Col2)'[hh]:mm'", 0))})
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bMXAmVis-quOfHCV4cbpBCRPLEXQa_oZUY18E_iatbI/edit#gid=828900112)